# What's the correct approach to this RLC circuit problem about RMS voltage?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, impedance, passive-networks, homework

How are you supposed to determine \$V_{C,RMS}\$ without R, L or C?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL2kd.png]

I drew a phasor diagram and used \$Z=\sqrt{R^2+(X_L-X_C)^2}\$ but am unsure on how to proceed from here as I do not have values of R, L or C.

Comment: Draw the phasor diagram.

Comment: I did, and using Pythagoras' Theorem I would be able to find the impedance and then the RMS current, but the problem is I don't know R, L or C to help me find those.

Comment: Please tag this as homework and then provide your working so far so we can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic LCR rule Vs=SQRT((Vl-Vc)^2+Vr^2) plus some algebra. This should be in the first few paragraphs of the LCR in series chapter of any AC theory textbook.

Have a look here... Page 3 has the information you need to solve this problem with only the voltages. learnabout-electronics.org/Downloads/ac_theory_module09.pdf

Also here... https://byjus.com/physics/lcr-circuit/

Answer (score 2):

This is a series resonant circuit. The reactive impedance of the capacitor is subtracted from that of the inductor.

You have the voltages for the overall circuit, the resistor and inductor. Since the voltage is proportional to the resistance/reactances you effectively know the information you need to know to do the calculation.

Draw a diagram of the overall circuit voltages i.e. 200, 100 and deduce the voltage due to combined reactance (of L and C) from that. It is 173.2 volts.

Now calculate voltage across the capacitor (bearing in mind the combined reactance is that of the inductor minus the capacitor).